# Plotting the basin of attraction of a Duffing oscillator with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, differential-equations

I have a system of ordinary differential equations, which turns out to have two attractors, one at (1, 0) and the other one at (-1, 0). I would like to plot a basin of attraction in a Cartesian coordinate, where there are two colors, showing which attractor a point at each point of coordinate will end up as time tends to positive infinity. However, I don't know how to plot such a graph with matplotlib. 
Here is what I have got up to now:

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import norm

"""
The system of ODE:
x' = y
y' = x - x**3 - gamma*y
"""

# The system of equation
def f(t, r, arg):
    return [r[1], r[0] - r[0] ** 3 - arg * r[1]]

# The Jacobian matrix
def jac(t, r, arg):
    return [[0, 1], [1 - 3 * r[0] ** 2, -arg]]

# r is the vector (x,y)
# Initial condition, length of time evolution, time step, parameter gamma
def solver(r0, t0, t1, dt, gamma):

    solution = ode(f, jac).set_integrator('dopri5')

    # Set the value of gamma
    solution.set_initial_value(r0, t0).set_f_params(gamma).set_jac_params(gamma)

    return solution


# The function to find the fixed point each starting point ends at
def find_fp(r0, t0, t1, dt, gamma):
    solution = solver(r0, t0, t1, dt, gamma)
    error = 0.01
    while solution.successful():
        if norm(np.array(solution.integrate(solution.t+dt)) - np.array([1, 0])) < error:
            return 1
        elif norm(np.array(solution.integrate(solution.t+dt)) - np.array([-1, 0])) < error:
            return -1

def fp(i, j, gamma):
    t0, t1, dt = 0, 10, 0.1
    return find_fp([i, j], t0, t1, dt, gamma)
```

I have defined several functions. `f` is a function defining the system of equation, `jac` the Jacobian matrix of the system, which serve as parameters to solve the ODE using the `dopri5` method of `scipy.integrate.ode` (the Kutta-Runge method). The `find_fp` function is defined to return the attractor that a point in the phase space will end up to, the return value `1` means the point will end up to (1, 0), and `-1` to (-1, 0). The functions seem to work well so far. However, I have no ideas how to plot a basin of attraction using what I have done with the `matplotlib` module. Are there any good ideas on that?

Comment: To your question: `plt.plot(i,j,'.b',ms=5)` should paint a large blue dot at coordinates `(i,j)`. Make the marker size smaller if you increase the density of the probed points.

Answer (score 1):

Quick'n'dirty: Select initial points close to the stationary points and compute the solution backwards for some time. Plot the solutions and color them according to attractor.

```
gamma = 1.2

def solution(x,y):
    return odeint(lambda u,t: -np.array(f(t,u,gamma)), [x,y], np.arange(0,15,0.01))

for i in range(-10,11):
    for j in range(-10,11):
        sol = solution(-1+i*1e-4, 0+j*1e-4);
        x,y = sol.T; plt.plot(x,y,'.b',ms=0.5);
        sol = solution(+1+i*1e-4, 0+j*1e-4);
        x,y = sol.T; plt.plot(x,y,'.r',ms=0.5);
plt.grid(); plt.show();
```

This gives the image

[image: phase portrait]

other values of `gamma` or longer integration intervals require careful handling, as the cubic term leads to hyper-exponential blow-up in the reverse time integration.

Comment: lutz lehmann ,,,can u draw the basin of attraction of 3 dimensional Lorenz and 4 dimensional chaotic system ?  kindly reply

Comment: and is there any link where i can find the plotting of basin of attraction for Lorenz system ?

Comment: @Zewo : What exactly do you mean? The Lorenz system (with standard parameters) has exactly one (strange) attractor, almost all solutions follow curves close to the "butterfly", oscillating in quasi-random intervals around one, then the other saddle point (with a strongly attracting direction, and slowly spiraling outwards in the perpendicular plane).

Comment: I mean that is this possible just visualization to make the basin of attraction for those systems having more than 2 system of differential equation . Like for Lorenz , rosller 3D and other 4D and 5D systems.